# Mock wrong input so that pytest catches ValueError

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm working on a project and I need to test my functions.
I'm struggling with this one:

```
def name():
    # Remember user's name
    while True:
        try:
            un = str(input("What's your name? "))
            if not un.isalpha():
                raise ValueError("Please enter a valid name.")
        except ValueError:
            continue
        break
    return un.capitalize()
```

I was able to mock an input to check the correctness of the function, but I can't seem to catch the error raised if something like "123" is input.

This is what I've written so far:

```
@mock.patch("project.input", return_value = "sol")
def test_name(self):
    actual_result = name()
    expected_result = "Sol"
    assert expected_result == actual_result


@mock.patch("project.input", return_value = "123", side_effect = ValueError)
def test_name_incorrect(self):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Please enter a valid name.") as e:
        result = name()
    assert str(e.value) == "Please enter a valid name."
```

"test_name" works, but "test_name_incorrect" doesn't, I even have to abort it with ctrl+c.

[Terminal message after keyboard interruption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uWug.png)

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Comment: "but I can't seem to catch the error raised if something like "123" is input.... Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?" The problem is that you expect an error to be raised. If an error is caught locally with `except`, then of course it will not be seen outside of the function. **That's the purpose** of `except`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `name` does not actually raise `ValueError` outside of its own scope, it catches the error raised in the `try` block and continues on the while loop. When you call `name()` in `test_name_incorrect`, the `name` function will loop indefinitely since a valid input is never received.

What you can do is create a separate function just for the validation that takes a string argument and raises an error if invalid, and test that separately.

See: [How to test if the right exception is raised and caught using unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918721/how-to-test-if-the-right-exception-is-raised-and-caught-using-unit-testing)

Could also look at the [capsys](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) fixture from pytest, if the above method is not preferred.

Comment: Great! Now I get it.
I wrote a simplified version of the original function, but now I'm wondering if this is OK to do so, because isn't the purpose of pytest is to test the original code? Right now, it's not really checking my function per se...

Comment: Well, instead of testing that `name` raises an error, you will be checking that the validator function does. You need to test what `name` returns when an invalid input is given, though in the version you have posted, it returns nothing and just keeps looping. Refactoring code to make it more testable is not only OK, it's a probably a good thing.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!! I've changed it to give it 10 tries, and after that it exits the program. Now I'm able to catch the Exception with pytest.raises :D